# its code i give below its give me error ..I used jupyter notebook and i write a code to drop the table columns and row but code give me error

Tags: pandas, jupyter

its my code

```
import pandas as pd area=pd.Series({"Peshawar":
    > 123456,"Karak":4784832,"Kohat":843932,"Mansehra":748392})
    > 
    > pop=pd.Series({"Peshawar":
    > 123456,"Karak":4784832,"Kohat":849392,"Mansehra":743392})
    > 
    > data=pd.DataFrame({"area":area,"pop":pop}) data
    > data.drop[:"peshawar",:"pop"]

code error
```

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent
call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9516/3219075350.py in

----> 1 data.drop[:"peshawar",:"pop"]

```
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Comment: Please improve the title of your question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: okay bro i will try my best

Answer (score 0):

Proper code to create your `data`:

```
area=pd.Series({"Peshawar":123456,"Karak":4784832,"Kohat":843932,"Mansehra":748392})
pop=pd.Series({"Peshawar":123456,"Karak":4784832,"Kohat":849392,"Mansehra":743392})
data=pd.DataFrame({"area":area,"pop":pop})
```

Remove a row:

```
>>> data.drop('Peshawar')
             area      pop
Karak     4784832  4784832
Kohat      843932   849392
Mansehra   748392   743392
```

Remove a column:

```
>>> data.drop('pop', axis=1)
             area
Peshawar   123456
Karak     4784832
Kohat      843932
Mansehra   748392
```

Remove a column and a row:

```
>>> data.drop('pop', axis=1).drop('Peshawar', axis=0)  # axis=0 is the default
             area
Karak     4784832
Kohat      843932
Mansehra   748392
```

Remove a cell is not possible but you can set it to NaN:

```
>>> data.loc['Peshawar', 'pop'] = float('nan')
             area        pop
Peshawar   123456        NaN
Karak     4784832  4784832.0
Kohat      843932   849392.0
Mansehra   748392   743392.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting is important in python, respect newlines!

```
import pandas as pd
area=pd.Series({"Peshawar": 123456,"Karak":4784832,"Kohat":843932,"Mansehra":748392})
pop=pd.Series({"Peshawar": 123456,"Karak":4784832,"Kohat":849392,"Mansehra":743392})

data=pd.DataFrame({"area":area,"pop":pop})
#data.drop[:"peshawar",:"pop"] # this is not valid in pandas
```